# PHP: Set different value and selected with foreeach with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I am new to php and trying to make dropdown list work with wordpress user table

I am trying to set user id as a value and want to display user_login but not able to get properly. It is rendering two time with wrong id. Here is my code

```
global $wpdb;
        $userids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users");
        $user_logins = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT user_login FROM $wpdb->users");

        echo '<select>';
        foreach($userids as $userid){
            foreach($user_logins as $user_login)
            echo '<option value="'.$userid.'" selected="'.$user_login.'">'.$user_login.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the two-queries that you're currently using, you can iterate with a counter instead of `foreach`:

```
$count = count($userids);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $userids[$i] . '" selected="' . $user_logins[$i] . '">' . $user_logins[$i] . '</option>';
}
```

You can combine the two queries into a single query using WordPress's `get_results()` method:

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_login FROM $wpdb->users");
echo '<select>';
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<option value="' . $user->ID . '" selected="' . $user->user_login . '">' . $user->user_login . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

It's also worth pointing out, the `option`'s `selected` attribute is being improperly used. It should only be set on a single option, and is generally set with a value of "selected", such as `selected="selected"`. Refer to the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option) for more info regarding that though.

Comment: This is wonderful and what I was looking for. As I am using wordpress so your second code works perfectly. However "whaatt" code also work the same but as I said I am using wordpress so preferable to use your second code. selected parameter I am calling dynamically for metabox so it will only use on one place and never repeats. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing two `foreach` loops, which is probably causing you problems due to mismatched duplicates between `$userids` and `$user_logins`. Instead, try using a `for` loop like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($userids); $i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$userids[$i].'" selected="'.$user_logins[$i].'">'.$user_logins[$i].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine but I would go with "newfurniturey" second code bcoz I am using wordpress so always prefer wordpress codex first. But your code I can use for other php stuffs. So giving you vote too..